# parallel.foreach vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, parallel.foreach

Could anyone please give me proper syntax how to write the following code in vb.net

```
public static void CopyFiles(string fromFolder, string toFolder)
{
    Parallel.ForEach<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(fromFolder, "*"), f =>
    {
        File.Copy(f, toFolder + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(f), true);
    });
}
```

I tried convertin this using developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb and converted code is :-

```
Public Shared Sub CopyFiles(fromFolder As String, toFolder As String)

    Parallel.ForEach(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(fromFolder, "*"), Function(f) 
    File.Copy(f, toFolder & "\" & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
    End Function)

End Sub
```

and its throwing compile time exception. Please let me know, what is going wrong in this code.

Comment: Where did you get the snippet from?

Comment: There are many code conversion websites out there.  SO is not one of them.

Comment: Dan-o I tried many sites. However they are not converting properly.

Comment: Ash Burlaczenco I got it from someone's blog

Comment: Try this site http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Zaf Khan..Tried this site too, overload error problems are coming after conversion from this website.

Comment: Converted code is :-                                                                   Public Shared Sub CopyFiles(fromFolder As String, toFolder As String)
Parallel.ForEach(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(fromFolder, "*"), Function(f) 
 File.Copy(f, toFolder & "\" & Path.GetFileName(f), True)

End Function) End Sub                                                            and its throwing compile time exceptio

Comment: What is the compile time exception?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a Function when you are not returning a value, try creating a Subroutine instead. See if this works.

```
Public Shared Sub CopyFiles(fromFolder As String, toFolder As String)
    Parallel.ForEach(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(fromFolder, "*"),
        Sub(f)
            File.Copy(f, toFolder & "\" & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
        End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: nice simplified example.  Cheers!